# Eclipse(pydev) changed text encoding (utf-8) to gibberish

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, python-3.x, pydev

I am working on python project with eclipse juno + pydev.

Today I open my eclipse and I see some of the hebrew text became gibbrish, 'א' became '�?' and some other letters changed as well.

I have tried changing the text encoding to UTF-8 by changing next values:

1. windows -> preferences -> workspace -> Text File Encoding -> other: UTF-8
2. windows -> preferences -> Content Type -> Text -> UTF-8 + Update
3. project -> properties -> Resource -> Text File Encoding -> UTF-8

No luck so far, I still see gibberish.

I also attempted to restore a previous checked in copy (earlier version) from TFS, but the problem remains.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: This may be late, but I found out that this setting is controlled via Properties for the python file. Right click the file and then see the Text file Encoding properties.